# Jquery slider with next prev image navigation

Tags: jquery, css, web

[slider](https://i.stack.imgur.com/j7pPo.jpg)

searching some slider solution like this at picture. if anyone can help provide me some links to website where i can find something similar

much thanks to everyone

Comment: Hello, you can find it your self, its better

Comment: if it would be that easy find something similar ... but its not so i come and ask if someo1 saw this somewhere

Answer (score 0):

I have created a jQuery Image Slider Plugin.

Here is the [`example`](https://jsfiddle.net/shwetaM/rv93wubx/) with annotated code.